# SwiftUI: Spacers won't scale down because BG Image will not adjust to device size

Tags: swiftui, vstack, zstack

I use a `ZStack` to display a fullscreen background image underneath the main UI. The main UI consists of a `VStack` with multiple views separated by flexible Spacers to scale down or up on different device sizes. Now I experience that the Spacers will not scale down on small devices because the background image on small devices remains bigger than the screen size and keeps the `ZStack` tall, see screenshot of the preview of iPhone 8. What am I doing wrong here?

**Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    var headerView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("HEADER").padding([.leading,.trailing], 100)
        }
    }
    
    var middleView: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("MIDDLE").padding([.leading,.trailing], 100)
        }
    }
    
    var bottomView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("BOTTOM").padding([.leading,.trailing], 100)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background Image
            Image("BgImg")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            // Main UI
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                headerView
                    .frame(height:222)
                    .background(Color.red)
                
                Spacer()
                
                middleView
                    .frame(height:155)
                    .background(Color.orange)
                
                Spacer()
                
                bottomView
                    .frame(height:288)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 32)
            .padding(.top, 54)
            // END Main UI
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        // END ZStack
    }
}
```

**Preview Screenshot:**
See blue border is bigger than device
[image]

**BG Image:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In described scenario you need to use `.background` instead of `ZStack`, such so *main view* form needed full-screen layout and image in background will not affect it.

So the layout should be like

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {

   // content here

}
.padding(.bottom, 32)
.padding(.top, 54)
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
.statusBar(hidden: true)
.background(

     // image here

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This indeed will keep the VStack unaffected by the background image size. However, I have problems to get the background image scaled to fullscreen. On iPhone 13 Pro it has a white border on the left and on iPhone 8 it has a white border left and right.

Comment: Works fine here. You have many hardcoded sizes which are incompatible with some form-factors. Try to avoid hardcoding (except minimal paddings) and then everything will fit on any device.

Comment: it seems to be due to the image size and the aspect ratio. While the iPhone 13 Pro and newer devices have an aspect ratio of 19.5:9, the iPhone 8 has an aspect ratio of 16:9 and hence the image is not filling the screen properly. I was able to fix that with putting .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) above the .background modifier

Comment: I would also put the safe edge modifier on the background view, rather than on the VStack and then adjusting padding to replicate the safe area. If a VStack edge hits the safe area boundary, the background will then automatically expand into the safe area without having to worry about specific padding values.